# Installing VS2013 project templates

Tags: visual-studio

With VS2013, I invoked the Extensions and Updates... item in the TOOLS menu, selected Online options and installed Durandal. Progress bars progressed and a restart of VS2013 was demanded and duly observed. When the dust settled, I expected to see a new kind of project here:

[image]

Somewhat disappointed, I went through the motions again and installed John Papa's Hot Towel SPA - with exactly the same outcome. Then I tried *again* but running as admin.

Has something gone wrong with my installation or am I looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer in the Q+A on the [VSIX page on the Microsoft website](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1eb8780d-d522-4dcf-bf56-56f0eab305c2)

> **Ado77** - If you have VS 2012 and VS 2013 installed, the template gets
>   installed under the 2012 sub template section in 2013.

It's a subtype of ASP.NET MVC4 Project for **both** VS2012 and VS2013. You don't see this project type till you dial back the NETFX to 4

As is inevitable with such things the version of knockout trails the current stable release, and unfortunately the template doesn't include knockout-jqueryui or anything else with a datepicker.